# TypeScript: Array.find could actually be undefined but it is returned as a fixed type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm blocked by a small problem:

```
const foo = ["foo", "bar"]; // type "string[]"
const foundFoo = foo.find(fooEl => fooEl === "notFooBar"); // type "string" -> why not "string | undefined"
```

I checked the type definitions of `array.find` and it does say it could possibly return undefined. Why is my environment saying the the `foundFoo` is of type `string` and not `string | undefined`?

The only other questions regarding this on StackOverflow that I found, asked pretty much the opposite why it "could" be undefined, so I'm not sure why my environment is saying the opposite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have [`strictNullChecks` options enabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) in your `tsconfig.json` file. When that option is not enabled, then all types (except for `any`) will basically resolve to `T | undefined`:

> In strict null checking mode, the `null` and `undefined` values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and `any` (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to `void`)

Comment: Is this because of the `not in the domain of every type` logic? Because whether undefined and null are interchangeable shouldn't affect the type result.

Comment: Yes. It seems like your tsconfig has that option turned off, which means `string` is essentially `string | undefined`. So when you do `const a: string = undefined`, that is actually allowed.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was turned off, so I will need to check whether this can be turned on for our codebase It's gonna take a lot of type error fixing :P

Comment: @josias We've had a similar issue too. It was painful turning on `strictNullChecks` because our solution/project threw a lot of warnings, but the good thing is that now we explicitly know if we expect, say, a string, or a string *or* undefined/null value. It's extremely useful, and also plays well with the null coalescence operator recently introduced.